# How to conditionally style VF component using VF formula with multiple if-else

Tags: visualforce

I have `PageBlockTable` where i want to put `different colors for cells` based on some `condition`

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!data}" var="rec" width="90%">
    <apex:column>
        <apex:facet name="header">Values</apex:facet>           
        <div style="text-align:center;font-weight:bold; background-color:{!IF(rec.age ==20,'red', 'blue')}">
            <apex:outputText value="{!rec.age}"/>
        </div> 
     </apex:column>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

The condition i have to check some thing like

```
if(age==20)
   background-color:red;
else if(age>20 && age<40)
   background-color:green;
else if(age>40 && age<55)
   background-color:blue;
else
   background-color:pink;
```

how can i achieve this.?

Please help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [CASE](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_variables_functions.htm) function handles this better than the IF function:

```
background-color:{!CASE(rec.age <= 20, 'red', rec.age > 20 && rec.age <= 40, 'green', rec.age > 40 && rec.age <= 55, 'blue', 'pink')}
```

Take care to cover all the possible age values: your pseudo code mapped 40 to pink.

**PS** Ignore this answer - as crop1645 points out this is not how CASE works. I think the OP must have got their answer from the comment thread so I won't delete this as that would also delete the comments.

Comment: @NullReferenceException But, when possible, *calculate the value in the controller and express it as a variable*. Expressions take up "more space" than simple variables, so if you have many rows of data, you could reach your view state size limit sooner.

Comment: @sfdcfox Yes i have many rows.can you please tell me how to do it.

Comment: In the wrapper class: `public string getColor() { if(age == 20) return 'red'; if(age < 40) return 'green'; if(age < 55) return 'blue'; return 'pink'; }`; in the page: `background-color: {!rec.color}`

Comment: @sfdcfox do i need to write seperate class for the same.?I have 3 columns Age , Age1, Age2 now i am writing style for each column for these 3.It would be great if it is possible to return the colors for 3 column.How can i create wrpper class for the perticular list and send the cell values to it.

Comment: @NullReferenceException No, they all go in the same class; just add one function per each field that has dynamic coloring.

Comment: @sfdcfox Ok i will try that.but my question is how to get rec.age in method..?public string getColor() { if(age == 20) return 'red'; if(age < 40) return 'green'; if(age < 55) return 'blue'; return 'pink'; } what is age here..do i need to create property for this.?

Comment: I presumed that you already have a property like this... but then again, you didn't include the original source for the class itself, so it was more an educated guess.

Comment: @sfdcfox i will work on it,and let you know..Thanks for your help

Comment: Keith (and trust me, I was looking at this for a completely different reason; I'm not auditing you :-) ) - how does that CASE formula even compile? The first argument is supposed to be an expression that is matched against the values of arguments 2,4,6, ... Is this some undocumented form of CASE?

Comment: @crop1645 No, you are right the answer is junk. Please downvote it (I would if I could); I assume the OP ignored it and got their answer from the comments...